# How could I use roSGScreen for open a new view? - Roku

Tags: roku, brightscript

Hi community I'm making an Roku app and I need to create window instance for can surf between it. The develop is inside the main fuction because is the only way that it works.

Also I need to create some moduls that it not depend of the main, I have been investigating and is nesessary the nodes use and task.

This's my code I wonder if you have some example using nodes and task

```
enter code here

     screen = CreateObject("roSGScreen")
     m.port = CreateObject("roMessagePort")
     screen.setMessagePort(m.port)
     scene = screen.CreateScene("PlayerScreen")
     screen.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before jumping into development, I will suggest to go through documentation-

https://developer.roku.com/en-gb/docs/developer-program/getting-started/roku-dev-prog.md

You can find some sample code here-

https://github.com/rokudev

Answer (score 0):

from your code snippet I do not see that you are opening any view. You can start with SGDEX framework https://github.com/rokudev/SceneGraphDeveloperExtensions, it encapsulates screen stack logic and contains a lot of samples so it will be easy to understand how show and close views.